# How to make doxygen display directory dependencies through function references instead of through include header files？

Tags: c, graph, directory, doxygen

I am trying to document my C code using doxygen.
If the DIRECTORY_GRAPH tag is set to YES then doxygen will show the dependencies a directory has on other directories in a graphical way.
The problem is that the  dependency relations are determined by the #include relations.
How to make doxygen display directory dependencies through function references?

A small eg：

```
dirA/a.c {funcA1,funcA2,funcA3} #include dirD/b.h , Reference function funcB2
dirB/b.c {funcB1,funcB2,funcB3} #include dirD/c.h , Reference function funcC2
dirC/c.c {funcC1,funcC2,funcC3} #include dirD/a.h , Reference function funcA3
dirD/a.h b.h c.h
```

All I know right now is that all directories depend on directory D.
But ,the actual directory dependency is A-dependent B ，B-dependent C and C-dependent A
There is a circular dependency: A->B->C->A,
Directory circular dependencies are considered architecturally unfriendly.

Thanks,
BITscu

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is in doxygen no such facility.

Comment: Are there any other tools that can do this? Thanks.